# Using JQuery getJSON method

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am attempting to pase a a JSON data using the JQuery getJSON function. 
The REST query is:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%20%3D%20%22london%22&format=json&jsoncallback=?
```

The script I'm using to parse 'data' to obtain the WOEID value doesnt seem to work below:

```
 $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                "q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%20%3D%20%22"+
                "london"+
                "%22&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
  console.log("json: " + data);
  var datatmp = data;
          if(data.results[0]){
            var data = filterData(data.results.place[0]);
           }
         }
       );
```

Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong?
[link text](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%20%3D%20%22london%22&format=json&jsoncallback=?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code needed a few tweaks, here's an updated version:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
      "q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%20%3D%20%22"+
      "london"+
      "%22&format=json&jsoncallback=json",
      function(data){
          if(data.query.results){
              $.each(data.query.results.place, function(i, v) {
                  console.log("woeid #" + i + ": " + v["woeid"]);
              });
          }
      });​
```

The `results` object is beneath `query`, so you need to go into there first, the above code iterates through the woeid's of the first place returned and alerts them...it's just a starter, not sure what you ultimately wanted to do with the `woeid` but hopefully this will get you started.  [You can see the above code working here](http://jsfiddle.net/tMzxh/1/).

Comment: Well how can I compete with that answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the code and it works perfect except some scenarios when only one woeid is returned..??

http://jsfiddle.net/g7N4U/

Many Thanks,

Comment: @nav - Strange that they change their structure in that case, anyway check for the single case, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g7N4U/1/

Comment: Thanks Nick for the single case :) It is strange how the json response changes its structure when returning just one result!

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
      if(data.results[0]){
        var data = filterData(data.results.place[0]);
       }
```

You check to see if `results[0]` exists but then you don't use it. I suspect your problem would be fixed by changing to this:

```
      if(data.results[0]){
        var data = filterData(data.results[0].place[0]);
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two key mistakes:

1. The correct parameter for specifying the callback in the YQL URL is `callback` rather than `jsoncallback`
2. The results are to be found in `data.query.results…` rather than `data.results…`

Also it is worth noting that there is a `data.query.count` value returned with the YQL results so you can see how many results were returned.

Comment: `jsoncallback` is to tell jQuery you're dealing with `jsonp`, this part is correct.  See the docs for details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: `jsoncallback` is specific to Flickr as used in the example on that page. YQL uses `callback`.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment, jQuery's looking for `callback=` in any case, the json prefix (or any prefix) is optional.  You can see the relevant jQuery source here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L212  As you can see in my answer (click the example link) his `jsoncallback` works since anything `callback=` matches on both ends :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a question: can you access that URL (http://query.yahooapis.com/...) even if it's not in your domain? Doesn't that violate the "same origin policy"?

Comment: jQuery uses JSONP with a callback function, so the same origin policy is not an issue.