# jQuery $.getJSON method still giving CORS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Here's my code based off this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604082/using-jquery-getjson-method)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#new-quote').click(function(){
    var url = 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?format=jsonp&jsonp=_';
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

This get's me the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?format=jsonp&jsonp=](http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?format=jsonp&jsonp=_). Redirect from '[http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?format=jsonp&jsonp=](http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?format=jsonp&jsonp=_)' to 'http://forismatic.com/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I've also tried the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#new-quote').click(function(){
    var url = 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?format=jsonp&jsonp=_';
    $.getJSON(url).done(update).fail(err);
    function update(response){
      console.log(response);
    }
    function err(jqxhr, textStatus, err){
      console.log('Request failed');
    }  
  });
});
```

And it gives me the same error. Along with the 'Request failed message'. I'm using jQuery 3.1.1. What am I missing here? Sorry if this is a duplicate but I've read the questions here and haven't found the answer

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) asks about the underlying concept of Access-Control-Allow-Origin. The guy also literally states that he doesn't want to use jsonp. I want use jsonp format with $.getJSON format and am not sure why it's not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245824/getjson-to-get-jsonp-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: @techouse that question deals with $.getJSON from a local json file.

Comment: @rckrd at the end of the question the person says he doesn't want to utilize jsonp

Comment: Does the service actually support JSONP? getJSON will not be JSONP without setting the callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery)

Comment: Typo: The callback placeholder character for jQuery is `?` not `_`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I had to tweak the url to `http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?` and it worked

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery.ajax you have a setting named **crossDomain**. By default is false to avoid CORS, set it to true to enable CORS calls with ajax.

***More Information*** : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: That just forces crossdomain behavior for a same origin request. The URL isn't the same origin so that will have no effect.